# Why can 'edition' be passed as option to Mage::run

Tags: magento-1.7, application

In Mage::run magento checks if an edition variable has been passed in its option array.

Why is this?

```
if (isset($options['edition'])) {
    self::$_currentEdition = $options['edition'];
}
```

I cant see anywhere in the codebase this is used.  Where is this used and why?

Comment: I can't imagine the case where this would be useful aside from having an updated version of Magento being dispatched with the ability to pretend to be a different version for compatibility with a remote system.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's used purely for reporting information about the API, see `Mage_Core_Model_Magento_Api::info`.